# Unable to access controller using AJAX in magento 2

Tags: controllers, ajax, magento2.3.3

I Have a very basic ajax function, where i want to access to the controller using AJAX.Below is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data', 'jquery/jquery.cookie'], function($,customerData){

    $(".verifybtn").click(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "<?php  echo $block->getUrl('cartamount/checkzip/index'); ?>",
            method: "POST",
            data: 1,
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

My controller file location is ( **app/code/Ayakil/CartAmount/Controller/Checkzip/Index.php**)

```
<?php
namespace Ayakil\CartAmount\Controller\Checkzip;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends Action {
protected $request;
public function __construct(Context $context,array $data = [])
{
    parent::__construct($context,$data);
}
public function execute() {
    echo "I am here";

}
}
```

Whenever i click the button i am getting a 404 not found error message.Something very basic, but i am unable to figured it out.
Great hep if some one find the issue.

Comment: try to return something instead of echo.

Comment: Can you load the url directly, e.g. by pasting it into a browser address bar? Is the URL correctly injected into the script?

Comment: @jiheison i ts my mistake, i did not add a frontname in router.xml for this custom module